# Adding custom breakpoints to material ui with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I know that in the `createMuiTheme()` function you are able to update the values of the breakpoints like so.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
})
```

I also know that Material UI (relatively) recently changed it where you can add custom values for breakpoints.

```
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      tablet: 640,
      laptop: 1024,
      desktop: 1280,
    },
  },
});
```

However, I am using Typescript and I can't get it to work by overriding the breakpoint values as they explain here:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints"
{
  interface BreakpointOverrides
  {
    xs: false; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    tablet: true; // adds the `tablet` breakpoint
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}
```

and instead get this error 
`Type '{ tablet: number; laptop: number; desktop: number; }' is not assignable to type 'BreakpointValues'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tablet' does not exist in type 'BreakpointValues'.`

Not sure what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope. I moved on but I would like to know answer so I can go back and fix.

Comment: I meet the same issue too

Comment: Hello there, if you are using typescript and you want to declare a module , then don't go nesting. Just do as mentioned ( this is for MUI v5.10.14)                                                            `declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    mobile: true; // adds the `mobile` breakpoint
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}` `const theme = createTheme({ breakpoints : { values : { ... your custom values }}})`

Answer (score 3):

I am working with typescript and breakpoints MaterialUI, I think you need to import and modify some interface as documentation says (https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme). So for example I have a Theme.tsx like this:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {BreakpointOverrides} from "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints"

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    tablet: true; // adds the `tablet` breakpoint
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}


declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    appDrawer: {
      width: React.CSSProperties['width']
      breakpoint: BreakpointOverrides
    }
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    appDrawer?: {
      width?: React.CSSProperties['width']
      breakpoint?: BreakpointOverrides
    }
  }
}
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      tablet: 400,
      laptop: 900,
      desktop: 1200
    }
  },})
```

Answer (score 3):

**I've been struggling with this issue for a while but I think I've found a working way to change/customize the breakpoints globally with ThemeOptions.**

```js
//themeOptions.ts
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles/createTheme";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    mobile: true; // adds the `mobile` breakpoint
    tablet: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}

export const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 650,
      desktop: 1200
    }
  }
};

//demo.tsx
import { useTheme, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
export default const Demo = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const mobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("mobile"));
  const mobileContent: JSX.Element = (<Box sx={{ bg: {mobile: "#000"}, color: "#fff" }}> Mui breakpoint mobile</box>);
  
  const otherContent: JSX.Element = (<Box sx={{ bg: {tablet: "#fff"}, color: "red" }}> Mui breakpoint not mobile</box>);
  
  return {mobile ? mobileContent : otherContent}
}

//app.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, } from "@mui/material";
import { themeOptions } from "./themeOptions";
import Demo from "./demo";

const App = () => {
  <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme(themeOptions)}>
    <Demo/>
  </ThemeProvider>
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CssBaseline />
      <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems is due to the version of material-ui. The 4.9.9 version of @material-ui/core would cause the error messages. When I update to 4.11.0, it work correctly.

Comment: You can find the issue was fixed in 4.9.14, **[theme] Fix override breakpoints (#20901) @JasonHK** showed in [material-ui/releases](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases)