# extend Mui Typescript breakpoints in typescript

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Getting a typescript error when trying to use custom names for breakpoint values:

```
Type '{ mobile: number; tablet: number; desktop: number;}' is not assignable to type '{ xs: number; sm: number; md: number; lg: number; xl: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mobile' does not exist in type '{ xs: number; sm: number; md: number; lg: number; xl: number; }'.
```

Here is my ThemProvider

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

<ThemeProvider
  theme={createTheme({
    breakpoints: {
      values: {
        mobile: 480,
        tablet: 750,
        desktop: 1076,
      },
    },
  })}
```

I tried adding a declaration file but then I got the error on import saying
Module '"@mui/material/styles"' has no exported member 'ThemeProvider'.
Module '"@mui/material/styles"' has no exported member 'createTheme'.

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false; // removes the `xs` breakpoint
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    mobile: true; // adds the `mobile` breakpoint
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a min but was addressing this as well. Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925965/adding-custom-breakpoints-to-material-ui-with-typescript) answer has the key. We will have to adjust for the new mui folder structure though.

```js
import { BreakpointOverrides } from '@mui/system/createTheme/createBreakpoints';

declare module '@mui/system/createTheme/createBreakpoints' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false;
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    mobile: true;
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
    desktopApp: true;
    largeDesktop: true;
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTheme' {
  interface ThemeOptions {
    breakpoint?: BreakpointOverrides;
  }
}

// ...

const theme = {
  // ...
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      desktopApp: 1024,
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 481,
      laptop: 768,
      desktop: 1024,
      largeDesktop: 1200,
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```